# PULP platform which uses modelsim

Tags: arduino, cvsimport, pulpcore

Hello Thank you for your attention,

am trying to install a PULP platform which uses modelsim. The last step is to execute this example code Helloworld and modelsim should open directly.

Tha attachment shows the error obtained after  : make helloworld.vsim

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlzU7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while getting that error:

you should enter pulp/sw/cmakelists.txt remove -64
error is closed